# Haproxy URL redirect

Tags: haproxy

Using haproxy 2.0.13-2

Having an issue with ACL's and redirect

I want to ACL on stuff.xyz.com/mycrap.aspx and redirect that to junk.abc.com

As a test I have an

ACL acl_stuff hdr(host) -i stuff.xyz.com/junk.aspx

use_backend be_stuff if acl_stuff

backend be_stuff

```
    stats enable
    option forwardfor
    http-response add-header X-Backend ohs1docker01
    server ohs1docker01 ohs1docker01.def.com:80 check
```

However even the ACL with the backend isnt working. I hit that page and I get a 404 which leads me to believe the ACL is not getting hit so the traffic is not getting to the backend.

Im hoping someone can give me some direction on this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use [http-response redirect](http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.4.git;a=blob;f=doc/configuration.txt;h=a48ba99d9c9ca465109fcaa213c9d239177fefdd;hb=HEAD#l7111)

```
http-response redirect code 301 location https://www.junk.abc.com if { hdr_beg(host) -i stuff.xyz.com }
```

The `acl acl_stuff hdr(host) -i stuff.xyz.com/junk.aspx` can't match because there is a mix of host and path.

To match `host` and `path` try this.

```
acl match_path path_beg /junk.aspx
acl match_host hdr_beg(host) -i stuff.xyz.com
http-response redirect code 301 location https://www.junk.abc.com if match_host match_path
```

Comment: So I looked at  your update and seems to have done the trick.

I did however use path rather than path_beg and it works like a charm.

Thank you for the help.

I feel stupid for not figuring this out when it was so easy